# What does a BPM of 92/100 mean?

Tags: notation, tempo

I’ve been trying to figure this out but have found nothing that I understand online. I have sheet music for the double bass and it has a BPM of 92/100 — Not really sure what that means but I figure it’s not less than one beat per minute, LOL. Does it mean I can play it at 92B BPM *or* 100 BPM?

Overall I’m just a confused beginner. All my searches have lead to YouTube videos of 92 BPM or 100 BPM songs/metronomes.

[image: Tempo mark: "crotchet = 92/100"]

---

I found the notation in an exercise from Ron Carter's [*Comprehensive Bass Method*](https://roncarterjazz.com/products/ron-carters-comprehensive-bass-method), p. 3: (but it also appears on pages 12, 22)

[image: Exercise for double bass in 1/2 position. The tempo indication is "crotchet = 92/100"]

Answer (score 6):

It's suggesting the tempo can be anywhere from 92bpm to 100bpm. The slash is unusual; typically it would be a dash: 92–100.

Answer (score 4):

That is not a standard way of indicating a tempo. It's a reasonable guess that it means "between 92 and 100," but it's just a guess. Suffice it to say that two numbers, separated by a single vertical stroke, *does not have a standard meaning* when giving metronome markings.

Answer (score -2):

In many programming languages "|", or vertical bar, means "or". I think that is what the writer intends. Using a "-" would have been much clearer.

Comment: In many programming languages, a single | is actually a bitwise or. `92|100=124`

Comment: @user1079505 Could also be `92||00` from the image ;)

Comment: This seems so unlikely as not to be worth a mention. First of all, it’s not a standard practice; one could also give the BPM in binary, but why would someone do that without explaining? Secondly, the single pipe is familiar to programmers, but although those are overrepresented here (because StackOverflow), it seems unlikely among the general musician population. Third, the single pipe doesn’t always even mean the same thing in all languages! Fourth, “92 OR 100” is not the same thing as “92 through 100,” and is an even more bizarre thing to ask for.